# How do I install selenium for python 3.7 instead of preinstalled 3.5 using pip3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium with python 3.7.3. By default python 3.5 was installed on my Linux machine. I had manually installed python 3.7 by the following method

- Downloaded and extracted the tar file.
- sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
- sudo make install

instead of altinstall so that only python3.7 is there in the system and is used everywhere required.

I then installed pip3 using the command :

- sudo apt install python3-pip

then installed selenium using pip :

- sudo pip3 install -U selenium

It installed it for python3.5 instead of 3.7. Now obviously, its giving error as Module not found.

I even tried copying those files in dist-package [contents of dist-packages folder inside folder 3.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JJ6E.png) to the folder 3.7. It gave issue of
"No module named zlib" If I try to install it using

1. sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
   It says already installed

What do I do?